# Do I need duplicate test methods; 1 for unit and 1 for integration tests?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq, integration-testing

I'm newer to unit testing and it seems like most of the information I find is on the unit testing side of things. I'm getting a good grasp around this and am planning on using MS Test Framework with Moq so I don't have to hand roll any mocks for my unit test dependencies.

Let's say I have the following *unit* test method:

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetCustomerByIDUnitTest()
{
   //Uses Moq for dependency for getting customer to make sure 
   //ID I set up is same one returned to test in Assertion
}
```

Do I have to create *another* identical test that instead uses the actual Entity Framework and Database call to make an integration test?

```
[TestMethod]
public void GetCustomerByIDIntegrationTest()
{
   //Uses actual repository interface for EF and DB to do integration testing
}
```

For the purpose of this question please leave topics about TDD or BDD out; I'm simple trying to determine if I physically need (2) separate tests and the manner of organizing these tests. Is this a requirement when doing both unit and integration testing?

Thanks!

Comment: This is not a programming question. It's a tool usage question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm, I hope I do not fail you by mentioning things you rather have unmentioned. But here my 2 cents on it. One disclaimer up-front. I use `nunit` with `RhinoMocks`, so syntax could be different, concepts are the same though.

**Yes, you need separate tests**. You can debate if you want to store the tests in the same test class, and tag them with `[Category("integrationtest")]` so that you can easily run your unit tests without running integration tests, and the other way around. With your TDD practices  (oops, I know you don't want me talking about that :)) you need your unit tests to be completed as fast as possible.

To look at this from a slightly different angle; you are not really duplicating your tests. Your integration tests validate the functionality, while your unit tests validate a method in isolation. So they can very well have completely different names. As long as they make sense to you (or if you develop something with a team: as long as it makes sense for your team).

I think the most important thing is that you find a way that works for you. There isn't really a right or wrong. I think it's a big plus that you are writing both unit tests and integration tests. How you organize them is kinda up to you. I had different approaches in different projects I participated in:

Project A:

- 1 test class for integration tests
- 1 test class for unit tests

That helped to create meaningful names for the test classes, they could capture the actual feature we are testing. As for the unit tests, the test class had the same name as the class that we are testing.

Project B:

- Mixed up integration tests with unit tests in one test class.

This worked fine as well, although we sometimes did have trouble finding an integration test. But tbh, with resharper at your side, how hard can it be :).

Answer (score 3):

In my opinion, it is somewhat situational. If I am working on a small personal project, then no, I just do the unit tests.

If it is a corporate / enterprise project then I do tend to do both unit and integration tests. However, keep unit and integration tests separated. Developers should be able to run unit tests frequently and quickly. Integration tests can be run less frequently because they usually take a long time to run. Usually I just run integration tests once before a commit, whereas I run unit tests much more frequently.

---

As an additional note, make your test names explain what should be happening. The test name `GetCustomerByIDUnitTest` really doesn't tell me much. Better would be something like: `GetCustomerByID_ReturnsTheCorrectUser_WhenAValidIdIsPassed` and conversely `GetCustomerByID_ReturnsNull_WhenNonExistantIdIsPassed`

I tend to favor a `What_Does_When` naming convention, but that too is a personal preference. In general, the more explanatory the better though.

Comment: Yes good point on the naming. I knew as I wrote it that it was a bit weak because I have read a ton on that. I was just trying to pseudo something quick, but I could have made it better. Question about your response - do you physically make separate 'Test' projects in VS.NET? If yes, what naming do you usually use? Or do you just separate the test types by folders within a single test project (i.e. 'Unit Tests' folder and 'Integration Tests' folder)?

Comment: I'll typically make 2 separate test projects, named something along the line of `MyProject.Tests` and `MyProject.IntgTests` because most test runners work well when you just give them 1 assembly to run, and it will run all the tests it finds.

Answer (score 0):

As I know you should have separate project for UnitTesting and IntegrationTesting.
The suggestion of This [book](http://books.google.nl/books?id=pZ49u0fSuGsC) is to create two projects and name them like `ProjectName.UnitTests` and `ProjectName.IntegrationTests`.
developers must run each of them separately and easily.

You can find many interesting topics and videos about testing [here](http://osherove.com/)

Comment: I'm interested in the link, but do you mind posting some specific links that are applicable to my questions as opposed to the homepage of a blog?